# How can I handle the "Undefined control sequence" error in pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

My first lines in convert.md format document are:

```
\thispagestyle{empty} %line1
\changepage{}{}{}{-1.5cm}{}{2cm}{}{}{} %line2
![The Little MongoDB Book, By Karl Seguin](title.png)\ %line3
\clearpage %line4
\changepage{}{}{}{1.5cm}{}{-2cm}{}{}{} %line5
```

So run commond lines as follows in win7 cmd:

```
pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex --template=latex_template.tex convert.md -o convert.pdf
```

But result shows:

```
Error producing PDF from Tex source.
!Undefined control sequence.
1.78 \changepage
```

And if delete "line1, line2, line4, line5", then commond line runs well.
What's the matter with the error, and how to handle it?
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think the Chinese language is relevant to this question? It might be, but why do you guess so?

Comment: oh,I'am sorry,yes,my arbitrary decision is wrong,here I modified the question title.

Comment: Try editing the produced document and adding `\usepackage{changepage}` before the `\changepage` line.

Comment: Thank you for your suggests,it's ok now with your method. My latex_template.tex is not complete enough before.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.